# does #include directive make sense for sql

Tags: c++, sql, directive

I know sql does not support #include directive, but I do not find a reason why this is not supported. I am working in a project which I may need to add this kind of support so that a sql file can include another one. Any obvious thing I may have missed? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pei

Comment: This is a great question and I totally agree that #include would be very useful.  Some databases may support it.  However, such a general question resulting in lots of discussion is not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: Most vendors have specific syntax for including other scripts.

Comment: If you are using mysql you can use the `SOURCE` command. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,270752,270752

Comment: Asked this way, the question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Try to rephrase it and ask "how do i include a Sql file in another one" and tag with the right db engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to imagine what `#include` would be used for.

- Constant definitions?
- Function definitions?
- Error messages?

In all the 100+k lines of SQL code I have written, I have never had the urge to include anything else.

The closest I come is to copy and paste and then modify a previously written query or `create table`.  I suppose if there were a macro parametrization scheme, I might devise a way to use includes, but mostly it would not be useful.

Comment: the idea is to reduce code duplication.in my project there are sql scripts with almost identical contents. and some fundamental sql script could be referenced by many others

Comment: the other motivation is that if a sql script can be broken down to small logical pieces, it is easier to "unit test" it

Comment: I never felt the urge to refactor, until I learned about it. I never felt the urge to use classes, until I learned about them. I never felt the urge to use standard libraries, until I started using them. I never felt ... etc. Sounds like an example of [this one](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail).